# I am using two libraries in one project and some of the jar files are conflicting.How do I resolve?

Tags: java, maven

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.aksw.deer.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>plugin-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <!-- @todo Customize this value  -->
    <name> Simple Example Plugin</name>
    <!-- @todo Customize this value  -->
    <description> Plugin Starter</description>
    <!-- @todo Customize this value  -->
    

    <scm>
        <!-- @todo Customize this value  -->
        <url>https://github.com/abc</url>
        <!-- @todo Customize this value  -->
        <connection>scm:git:https://github.com/abc.git</connection>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <!-- @todo Customize this value  -->
        <plugin.id>OntologyMatchingPlugin</plugin.id>
        <!-- @todo Customize this value  -->
        <plugin.class>org.aksw.deer.plugin.example.OntologyMatchingPlugin</plugin.class>
        <!-- @todo Customize this value  -->
        <plugin.version>1.0.0</plugin.version>
        <!-- @todo Customize this value  -->
        
        <plugin.dependencies />

        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <deer.version>2.3.0</deer.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>data-local</id>
            <name>data</name>
            <url>file://${project.basedir}/repo</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>maven.aksw.internal</id>
            <name>abcs</name>
            <url>https://maven.aksw.org/repository/internal/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>maven.aksw.snapshots</id>
            <name>University , AKSW Maven2 Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://maven.aksw.org/repository/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>https://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>


    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>${maven.compiler.source}</release>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <annotationProcessorPath>
                            <groupId>org.pf4j</groupId>
                            <artifactId>pf4j</artifactId>
                            <version>3.0.1</version>
                        </annotationProcessorPath>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <annotationProcessors>
                        <annotationProcessor>org.pf4j.processor.ExtensionAnnotationProcessor
                        </annotationProcessor>
                    </annotationProcessors>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                        <version>7.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>aggregate</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <includeDependencySources>true</includeDependencySources>
                    <dependencySourceIncludes>
                        <dependencySourceInclude>org.aksw.deer:*</dependencySourceInclude>
                        <dependencySourceInclude>org.aksw.faraday_cage:*</dependencySourceInclude>
                    </dependencySourceIncludes>
                    <links>
                        <link>https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena</link>
                    </links>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forkCount>0</forkCount>
                    <argLine>-Xms256m -Xmx8G</argLine>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                    <useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-plugin</finalName>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <attach>false</attach>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Plugin-Id>${plugin.id}</Plugin-Id>
                            <Plugin-Version>${plugin.version}</Plugin-Version>
                            <Plugin-Provider>${plugin.provider}</Plugin-Provider>
                            <Plugin-Class>${plugin.class}</Plugin-Class>
                            <Plugin-Dependencies>${plugin.dependencies}</Plugin-Dependencies>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- For depending of Logmap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>uk.ox.logmap</groupId>
            <artifactId>logmap-matcher</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId> <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId> 
            <version>2.7</version> <scope>test</scope> </dependency> -->
        
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId> 
            <version>1.6.4</version> </dependency> -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.owlapi/owlapi-distribution -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>owlapi-distribution</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.19</version>
            
        </dependency>


        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId> <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId> 
            <version>2.7</version> <scope>test</scope> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId> 
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId> <version>2.7</version> <scope>test</scope> 
            </dependency> -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aksw.deer</groupId>
            <artifactId>deer-core</artifactId>
            <version>${deer.version}</version>
            <!-- !!! VERY IMPORTANT -->
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>httpclient</groupId>
                    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>httpclient</groupId>
                    <artifactId>httpclient-cache</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>httpclient</groupId>
                    <artifactId>httpclient-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j-impl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I'm getting error as:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.ja
va:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.pf4j.DefaultPluginFactory.create(DefaultPluginFactory.java:64)
        at org.pf4j.PluginWrapper.getPlugin(PluginWrapper.java:79)
        at org.pf4j.AbstractPluginManager.startPlugins(AbstractPluginManager.java:331)
        at org.aksw.deer.DeerController.<clinit>(DeerController.java:98)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl cannot be cast to class jav
ax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory (org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl is in unnamed module of loader 'app
'; javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory is in unnamed module of loader org.pf4j.PluginClassLoader @332796d3)
        at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.newDocumentBuilder(XmlConfiguration.java:191)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.<init>(XmlConfiguration.java:92)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(XmlConfigurationFactory.java:44
)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:510)

        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:450)

        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:257)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:560)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:577)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:212)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:152)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:103)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:42)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
        at org.aksw.deer.plugin.example.KGMatchingPlugin.<clinit>(KGMatchingPlugin.java:10)
        ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You can relocate classes in maven:
[maven class relocation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html)

Answer (score 0):

The best way for finding conflict in your pom file is using:

```
mvn dependency:tree > somefile.txt
```

or

```
 mvn dependency:tree -DoutputFile=myFile.dot -DoutputType=dot
```

then you can search for a specific library and you will be able to find out if there is any duplicate library with a different version in your dependency.
Also, The `verbose` mode tells the tree plugin to show dependencies that are duplicates of another or in conflict with another’s version.

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```